# How the Hachamim did not recognize Shalmai

Tags: agada-stories-legends, king-solomon, sheidim-demons

The legend of the Talmud is known that Shalmai replaced Solomon in his kingdom for a period of time. After all, Solomon, by virtue of his position as king, had to pass judgments and discuss with the Sanhedrin. And if so, how did the Sanhedrin not notice that it was demon and not Solomon? Gave up as a result, if demon was a judge, then all of his judgments are invalid and if so, were all the trials made during Shalmai's period perverted trials? And did Solomon correct this after his return to the kingdom?

Comment: Do you have any sources?

Comment: Are you referring to Ashmedai (the king of demons) as per Gittin 68b - https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.68b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to Ashmedai then the maaseh is related in Gittin 68b (starting [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.68b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and it would seem from the continuation of the story that the Chachomim were indeed tricked until proven otherwise:

> הָיָה מְחַזֵּר עַל הַפְּתָחִים, כֹּל הֵיכָא דִּמְטָא, אָמַר: ״אֲנִי קֹהֶלֶת הָיִיתִי מֶלֶךְ עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל בִּירוּשָׁלִָים״. כִּי מְטָא גַּבֵּי סַנְהֶדְרִין, אֲמַרוּ רַבָּנַן: מִכְּדִי שׁוֹטֶה – בַּחֲדָא מִילְּתָא לָא סְרִיךְ, מַאי הַאי? אֲמַרוּ לֵיהּ לִבְנָיָהוּ: קָא בָעֵי לָךְ מַלְכָּא לְגַבֵּיהּ? אֲמַר לְהוּ: לָא. שְׁלַחוּ לְהוּ לְמַלְכְּווֹתָא: קָאָתֵי מַלְכָּא לְגַבַּיְיכוּ? שְׁלַחוּ לְהוּ: אִין, קָאָתֵי. שְׁלַחוּ לְהוּ: בִּידְקוּ בְּכַרְעֵיהּ. שְׁלַחוּ לְהוּ: בְּמוּקֵי קָאָתֵי וְקָא תָבַע לְהוּ בְּנִידּוּתַיְיהוּ; וְקָא תָבַע לַהּ נָמֵי לְבַת שֶׁבַע אִימֵּיהּ. אַתְיוּהּ לִשְׁלֹמֹה, וְהַבוּ לֵיהּ עִזְקְתָא, וְשׁוּשִׁילְתָּא דַּחֲקִוק עָלֶיהָ שֵׁם. כִּי עָיֵיל, חַזְיֵיהּ, פְּרַח
>
> Shlomo went begging from door to door (collecting charity), and wherever he arrived he would say: “I, Ecclesiastes, was king over Israel in Jerusalem” (Koheles 1:12). When he arrived at the Sanhedrin, the sages said: A madman does not speak consistently of one matter. What is this? They said to Benayahu: Does the king require you to be with him? Benayahu said to them: No. They sent to the queens and asked: Does the king come to you? The queens answered "Yes, he comes." They sent back: "Check his feet" (Sheidim have feet like chickens). They sent back (a response to the sages): He comes in socks, (so it is not possible to see his feet). And he comes when we are unclean, and even makes advances to his mother BasSheva. They brought Shlomo and returned to him his ring and his chain, of which the the Ineffable Name was engraved. When he entered, Ashmedai saw him and flew off.

This story is repeated albeit with reference to an Angel<sup>1</sup> not a sheid in [Rus Rabbah 5:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth_Rabbah.5.6?lang=bi) and says expressly:

> מַלְאָךְ יָרַד בִּדְמוּת שְׁלֹמֹה וְיָשַׁב לוֹ עַל כִּסְאוֹ
>
> An angel descended in the form of Shlomo and sat on his throne...

So according to this Midrash the imposter looked exactly like Shlomo and thereby fooled the onlookers.

---

<sup>1</sup> Refer to the [Yefeh Anaf](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth_Rabbah.5.6?lang=bi&p2=Yefeh_Anaf_on_Ruth_Rabbah.5.6.4&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) on the Midrash which brings the Gemara in Gittin saying that he was ousted by Ashmedai.